# webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default. This is no longer the case

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

im getting the errors:

22 errors have detailed information that is not shown.
Failed to compile.
webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'C:\Users\joshm\Downloads\New folder (14)\myapp\node_modules\body-parser\lib'
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

```
If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib") }'
        - install 'browserify-zlib'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "zlib": false }
asset static/js/bundle.js 2.84 MiB [emitted] (name: main) 1 related asset
asset index.html 1.67 KiB [emitted]
asset asset-manifest.json 190 bytes [emitted]
cached modules 2.42 MiB (javascript) 28.3 KiB (runtime) [cached] 271 modules

WARNING in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js 74:13-25
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js 26:11-28
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js 19:12-36
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js 10:0-41
 @ ./src/Login.js 6:0-35 29:23-36
 @ ./src/App.js 8:0-28 39:38-43
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 10:33-36

1 warning has detailed information that is not shown.
Use 'stats.errorDetails: true' resp. '--stats-error-details' to show it.

ERROR in ./node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js 20:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'C:\Users\joshm\Downloads\New folder (14)\myapp\node_modules\body-parser\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib") }'
        - install 'browserify-zlib'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "zlib": false }
 @ ./node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js 21:11-29
 @ ./node_modules/body-parser/index.js 134:15-42
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js 13:17-39
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js 10:0-41
 @ ./src/Login.js 6:0-35 29:23-36
 @ ./src/App.js 8:0-28 39:38-43
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 10:33-36

ERROR in ./node_modules/content-disposition/index.js 19:15-39
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\joshm\Downloads\New folder (14)\myapp\node_modules\content-disposition'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js 15:25-55
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js 27:10-31
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js 10:0-41
 @ ./src/Login.js 6:0-35 29:23-36
 @ ./src/App.js 8:0-28 39:38-43
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 10:33-36

ERROR in ./node_modules/cookie-signature/index.js 4:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\joshm\Downloads\New folder (14)\myapp\node_modules\cookie-signature'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
        - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js 35:11-43
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js 27:10-31
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js 10:0-41
 @ ./src/Login.js 6:0-35 29:23-36
 @ ./src/App.js 8:0-28 39:38-43
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 10:33-36

ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js 12:17-41
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\joshm\Downloads\New folder (14)\myapp\node_modules\destroy'
 @ ./node_modules/send/index.js 19:14-32
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js 45:11-26
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js 27:10-31
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js 10:0-41
 @ ./src/Login.js 6:0-35 29:23-36
 @ ./src/App.js 8:0-28 39:38-43
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 10:33-36

ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js 14:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\joshm\Downloads\New folder (14)\myapp\node_modules\destroy'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
        - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
 @ ./node_modules/send/index.js 19:14-32
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js 45:11-26
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js 27:10-31
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js 10:0-41
 @ ./src/Login.js 6:0-35 29:23-36
 @ ./src/App.js 8:0-28 39:38-43
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 10:33-36

ERROR in ./node_modules/etag/index.js 18:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\joshm\Downloads\New folder (14)\myapp\node_modules\etag'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
        - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/utils.js 25:11-26
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js 30:18-48 32:25-62 34:19-50
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js 19:12-36
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js 10:0-41
 @ ./src/Login.js 6:0-35 29:23-36
 @ ./src/App.js 8:0-28 39:38-43
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 10:33-36

ERROR in ./node_modules/etag/index.js 20:12-31
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\joshm\Downloads\New folder (14)\myapp\node_modules\etag'
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/utils.js 25:11-26
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js 30:18-48 32:25-62 34:19-50
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js 19:12-36
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js 10:0-41
 @ ./src/Login.js 6:0-35 29:23-36
 @ ./src/App.js 8:0-28 39:38-43
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 10:33-36

ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js 28:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\joshm\Downloads\New folder (14)\myapp\node_modules\express\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
        - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "http": false }
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js 19:12-36
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js 10:0-41
 @ ./src/Login.js 6:0-35 29:23-36
 @ ./src/App.js 8:0-28 39:38-43
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 10:33-36



22 errors have detailed information that is not shown.
Use 'stats.errorDetails: true' resp. '--stats-error-details' to show it.

webpack 5.69.1 compiled with 22 errors and 1 warning in 2554 ms

webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    
    resolve: {
        fallback: {
            "fs": false
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem. And this solution will help you:

1. npm i node-polyfill-webpack-plugin
2. Write this code into **vue.config.js**

```js
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require('node-polyfill-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [new NodePolyfillPlugin()]
  }
};
```

Comment: Worked for me. I was using vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder with vue 3.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when you import an unrecognized module into your Application. Check all the modules you are importing from expressjs.

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent 2 evenings tried to figure out this issue! In my case it was autocomplete added to a vue component `import { response } from 'express';` ‍♀️